# C# Resolve hostname with Dns to IP Address

Tags: c#, dns, active-directory, ip-address, computer-name

Got this program i am writing in my office in C#.

So i can read all Computer Names From the Domain, fill them into a List and print them out.

Using this Code :

```
    `private void FindComputersInAD()
    {
    List<string> computerNames = new List<string>();
        DirectoryContext dirCtx = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "domain.com");
        using (Domain usersDomain = Domain.GetDomain(dirCtx))
        using (DirectorySearcher adsearcher = new DirectorySearcher(usersDomain.GetDirectoryEntry()))
        {
            adsearcher.Filter = ("(objectCategory=computer)");                                                                                                          
            adsearcher.SizeLimit = 0;
            adsearcher.PageSize = 250;

            // Let searcher know which properties are going to be used, and only load those
            adsearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

            foreach (SearchResult searchResult in adsearcher.FindAll())
            {
                if (searchResult.Properties["name"].Count > 0)
                {
                    string computer = (string)searchResult.Properties["name"][0];                      
                    computerNames.Add(computer);
                }
            }
        }
        computerNames.Sort();
        computerNames.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }`
```

Now that i got all the Computer Names, i would like to get their IP Addresses as well.
But there is no such property.

I googled a lot and tried a few things but nothing works.

Can I use the DNS class to do this ?

I use this method to get the Host IP Address :

```
private void GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        string _subString;
        var _host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var _ip in _host.AddressList)
        {
            if (_ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                _subString = _ip.ToString().Substring(_ip.ToString().Length - 2);
                //When a IP Address ends with .1, don't add it to the List.
                if (_subString != ".1")
                {
                    _hostIPAddress = _ip.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can I use this also somehow to get the IP Addresses of the Computers ?

I would be very happy if you can help me :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found myself an answer.
Since all the computers are in the same domain i openend cmd and tried nslookup.
And it returned the IP Address i wanted.

So i just built a C# DNSLookup Method, looks like this :

```
 private void DNSLookup(string computerNameOrAddress)
    {
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(computerNameOrAddress);

        IPAddress[] ips = hostEntry.AddressList;
        foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Address: {0}", ip);        
        }
    }
```

Anyway thanks for looking :)